# Filter via condition on one relation and eager load another relation records

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api, backend

I have this code I want to get list users with a role of  teacher where each teacher  will have one object for the personal detail one object for the school detail

```
 public function index(){
  $teachers = User::whereHas('roles' , function($q){$q->where('name','isTeacher');})->get();
            foreach($teachers as $teacher){
                $teacher_id = $teacher->id;
                $teacherinSchool = School_Teachers::where('user_id', $teacher_id)->first();
               $teacherinSchool = $teacherinSchool->school_id;
                $School = School::where('id', $teacherinSchool)->first();
                return response(['teacher'=>$teacher, 'school'=>$School]); 
            }
    }
```

this is what i got but i am expecting to have more that one teacher but it takes the first teacher in the list and display the objects

[output in the postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOYKO.png)

i have 5 models involved here User model, Role model, User_Role model, school model and school_teacher model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to point out

- You are doing queries within a loop (**foreach**) not good for performance.
- Having `return response()` within foreach loop hence only 1 Teacher record is available
- You are getting just the first record for School_Teachers & School

For what you are trying to do can be done more efficiently as under

```php
public function index()
{
    $teachers = User::whereHas('roles', fn($query) => $query->where('name', 'isTeacher'))->get();

    $schoolIds = School_Teachers::whereIn('user_id', $teachers->pluck('id')->toArray())->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $schools = School::whereIn('id', $schoolIds)->get();

    return response()->json(['teachers' => $teachers, 'schools' => $schools]);
}
```

However that is also not optimal, still can be better

- Define a relation on `User` model to link it to `School` model via `School_Teachers` (many-to-many)
- Then in a single query you can get `User`(s) which have role of `isTeacher` with their `School`

For eg: Say you have a table `school_teachers` which has columns for `user_id`, `school_id` (kind of pivot table) where each record can be uniquely identified by `['user_id', school_id']` composite key - unique index on database table.

Then you can define direct (many-to-many) relation between `User` and `School`

```php
//User model
public function schools()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(School::class, 'school_teachers', 'user_id', 'school_id');
}
```

```php
//School model
public function teachers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'school_teachers', 'school_id', 'user_id');
}
```

In controller you can do

```php
public function index()
{
    $teachers = User::with('schools')
        ->whereHas(
            'roles',
            fn($query) => $query->where('name', 'isTeacher')
        )
        ->get();

    return response()->json(['teachers' => $teachers]);
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks Mr @Donkarnash, I have applied the second view of yours and it is really helping me

Comment: Noted that I have already did it